# Assign new value to null javascript object members

Tags: javascript, json

I am having issues figuring out how to find the nulls in my object and replace them with 0's. I was able to access the correct member at one point but once it left the loop their were no longer assigned the 0. I am fairly new to working with objects in js so I am pretty lost. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
var data = { 
    0 : {
         Day1: {
               Hours: 6,
               Minutes: null
         },
         Day2: {
               Minutes: 45
         },
         Day3: {
               Hours: 8,
               Minutes: 15
         },
    1 : {
         Day1: {
               Hours: 6,
               Minutes: 20
         },
         Day2: {
               Hours: 45
               Minutes: null
         },
         Day3: {
               Hours: 8,
               Minutes: 15
         }
};


for (var item in data) {
    for (var item2 in item) {
         item[item2].Hours = item[item2].Hours || 0;
         item[item2].Minutes = item[item2].Minutes || 0;
    }
}

//Ignore this line. Just assigning onject to angular scope when finished
$scope.timeInfo = data;
```

Comment: Remember that in these `for in` loops, the `item` and `item2` refers to the **keys**, not the **values** (my point is that `item[item2]` doesn't make sense). So for example, `item` will be `"0"` and `"1"`

Comment: FWIW: I would probably change the data to use arrays for both levels.

Comment: @osiris355, were you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: Yes and sorry for the late response. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ian is correct when he says that in `for (variable in object)` loops variables refers to the object key property names. So in your case, one way to achieve your objective is the following:

(NOTE: I went ahead and added some missing braces in your `data` object.)

```
var data = { 
    0 : {
         Day1: {
               Hours: 6,
               Minutes: null
         },
         Day2: {
               Minutes: 45
         },
         Day3: {
               Hours: 8,
               Minutes: 15
         }
    },
    1 : {
         Day1: {
               Hours: 6,
               Minutes: 20
         },
         Day2: {
               Hours: 45,
               Minutes: null
         },
         Day3: {
               Hours: 8,
               Minutes: 15
         }
    }
};


for (var item in data) {
    for (var item2 in data[item]) {
         data[item][item2].Hours = data[item][item2].Hours || 0;
         data[item][item2].Minutes = data[item][item2].Minutes || 0;
    }
}
```